# Installing PyflyCapture2 Python problems with C++ building

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a remote camera control and using a Point Grey fl3-u3-32s2c-cs. I would like to control my camera, retrieve images and so on using Python. FLIR (previously Point Gre) provides FlyCapture, which is the SDK used to work with FLIR USB 2.0, USB 3.0, Gigabit Ethernet or FireWire cameras. Since I want to work exclusively with Python, I found the python package pyflycapture2 that would fit my needs. However, when I tried to install the python package pyflycapture2, I got the error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools". And that's what I did: Download Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio, then I selected Workloads → Desktop development with C++, then for Individual Components, I selected only Windows 10 SDK and C++ x64/x86 build tools.
When I try to run `pip install pyflycapture` in the command line, I get the following error message (shown in the image file):
[Error message when running `pip install pyflycapture2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZAF7.png)

By lookin at the error message, it seems that it couldn't find the c++ file, in fact one part of the error says: `src\flycapture2.c(235): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'FlyCapture2Defs_C.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`
I have added the folder where I installed visual studio and where the building tools in c++ are installed into the path, but for some reason I keep getting the same error. I’m working with Windows 10 andq  64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. Any hwlp would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you include c++ Cmake tools for windows

Comment: Yes, I did and when I search for the file 'FlyCapture2Defs_C.h' in my directory then I can find it.